# Where I can find or set applicationID for Firebase in my react native expo application?

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I want to add Firebase to my application, where I can find android package name (it says: "Your package name is generally the applicationID in your app-level build.gradle file") in my React Native expo application? Am I missing some files or should I create it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your package name is the id you choose like com.app.myapp and specify in your app.json (in android/package and ios/bundleIdentifier, more [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#properties)).

Expo will use this when building your app.

If you are still working in Expo client but still want to use firebase javascript SDK, you can set it to anything you want.

The link will be made based on the appId firebase will provide and that you will have to specify when initializing firebase in your app.